# pig script to sample 10 chunks of training data, pig script is jammed

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, apache-pig, sampling, bootstrapping

**BACKGROUND**

I have a binary classification task where the data is highly imbalanced. Specifically, there are
way more data with label 0 than that with label 1. In order to solve this problem, I plan to subsampling
data with label 0 to roughly match the size of data with label 1. I did this in a pig script. Instead of
only sampling one chunk of training data, I did this 10 times to generate 10 data chunks to train 10 classifiers
similar to bagging to reduce variance.

**SAMPLE PIG SCRIPT**

```
---------------------------------
-- generate training chunk i
---------------------------------
-- subsampling data with label 0
labelZeroTrainingDataChunki = SAMPLE labelZeroTrainingData '$RATIO';

-- combine data with label 0 and label 1
trainingChunkiRaw = UNION labelZeroTrainingDataChunk1,labelOneTrainingData;

-- join two tables to get all the features back from table 'dataFeatures'
trainingChunkiFeatures = JOIN trainingChunkiRaw BY id, dataFeatures BY id;
-- in order to shuffle data, I give a random number to each data
trainingChunki = FOREACH trainingChunkiFeatures GENERATE
                        trainingChunkiRaw::id AS id,
                        trainingChunkiRaw::label AS label,
                        dataFeatures::features AS features,
                        RANDOM() AS r;
-- shuffle the data
trainingChunkiShuffledRandom = ORDER trainingChunki BY r;

-- store this chunk of data into s3
trainingChunkiToStore = FOREACH trainingChunkiShuffledRandom GENERATE
                        id AS id,
                        label AS label,
                        features AS features;

STORE trainingChunkiToStore INTO '$training_data_i_s3_path' USING PigStorage(',');
```

In my real pig script, I do this 10 times to generate 10 data chunks.

**PROBLEM**

The problem I have is that if I choose to generate 10 chunks of data, there are so many mapper/reducer tasks, more than 10K. The majority of
mappers do very little things (runs less 1 min). And at some point, the whole pig script is jammed. Only one mapper/reducer task could run and all other mapper/reducer tasks are blocked.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

1. In order to figure out what happens, I first reduced the number of chunks to generate to 3. The situation was less severe. 
   There were roughly 7 or 8 mappers running at the same time. Again these mappers did very little things (runs about
   1 min).
2. Then, I increased the number of chunks to 5, at this point, I observed the the same problem I have when I set the number of chunks
   to be 10. At some point, there was only one mapper or reducer running and all other mappers and reducers were blocked.
3. I removed some part of script to only store id, label without features

   ```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- generate training chunk i
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- subsampling data with label 0
   labelZeroTrainingDataChunki = SAMPLE labelZeroTrainingData $RATIO;

   -- combine data with label 0 and label 1
   trainingChunkiRaw = UNION labelZeroTrainingDataChunki, labelOneTrainingData;

   STORE trainingChunkiRaw INTO '$training_data_i_s3_path' USING PigStorage(',');
   ```

This worked without any problem.

4. Then I added the shuffling back

   ```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- generate training chunk i
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------

   -- subsampling data with label 0
   labelZeroTrainingDataChunki = SAMPLE labelZeroTrainingData $RATIO;

   -- combine data with label 0 and label 1
   trainingChunkiRaw = UNION labelZeroTrainingDataChunki, labelOneTrainingData;
   trainingChunki = FOREACH trainingChunkiRaw GENERATE
                       id,
                       label,
                       features,
                       RANDOM() AS r;
   -- shuffle data
   trainingChunkiShuffledRandom = ORDER trainingChunki BY r;
   trainingChunkiToStore = FOREACH trainingChunkiShuffledRandom GENERATE
                       id AS id,
                       label AS label,
                       features AS features;

   STORE trainingChunkiToStore INTO '$training_data_i_s3_path' USING PigStorage(',');
   ```

The same problem reappears. Even worse, at some point, there was no mapper/reducer running. The whole program hanged without making any progress. I added another machine and the program ran for a few minutes before it jammed again. Looks like there are some dependency issues here.

**WHAT'S THE PROBLEM**

I suspect there are some dependency which leads to deadlock. The confusing thing is that before shuffling, I already
generate the data chunks. I was expecting the shuffling could be executed in parallel since these data chunks are independent
with each other.

Also I noticed there are many mappers/reducers do very little thing (exists less than 1 min). In such case, I would 
imagine the overhead to launch mappers/reducers would be high, is there any way to control this?

1. What's the problem, any suggestions?
2. Is there standard way to do this sampling. I would imagine there are many cases where we need to do these subsampling like bootstrapping or bagging. So, there might be some standard way to do this in pig. I couldn't find anything useful online.
   Thanks a lot

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

1. The size of table 'labelZeroTrainingData' is really small, around 16MB gziped. 
   table 'labelZeroTrainingData' is also generated in the same pig script by filtering.
2. I ran the pig script on 3 aws c3.2xlarge machines.
3. table 'dataFeatures' could be large, around 15GB gziped.
4. I didn't modify any default configuration of hadoop.
5. I checked the disk space and memory usage. Disk space usage is around 40%. Memory usage is around 90%. I'm not sure memory is the problem. Since
   I was told if the memory is the issue, the whole task should fail.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I think I figure out something. The problem is likely to be the multiple `STORE` statements there. Looks like pig script will be running in batch by default. So, for each chunk of the data, there is a job running which leads to lack of resource, e.g. slots for mapper and reducer. None of the job could finish because each needs more mapper/reducer slots.

**SOLUTION**

1. use piggybank. There is a storage function called MultiStorage which might be useful in this case. I had some version incompatible issue between piggybank and hadoop. But it might work.
2. Disable pig executing operations in batch. Pig tries to optimize the execution. I simply disable this multiquery feature by adding -M. So, when you run pig script, it looks like something `pig -M -f pig_script.pg` which executes one statement at a time without any optimization. This might not be ideal because no optimization is done. For me, it's acceptable.
3. Use `EXEC` in pig to enforce certain execution order which is helpful in this case.